# does kerberos encrypt only the authentication or all client communications?

Tags: kerberos

Does kerberos encrypt only the authentication process or all client communications?

I was under the impression it was like a VPN for the LAN.

So that all LAN communications are encrypted. Just like all internet communications are encrypted with a VPN.

Regards
Aubrey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kerberos is quite capable of encrypting traffic between client and server, but depending on exactly how kerberos is used in the application, it may or may not be using the kerberos session keys to encrypt the traffic.

The kerberos protocol provides the means to exchange a session key that can be used to encrypt message traffic after the initial authentication exchange. Encrypted message exchange is generally the default for protocols that actually use GSSAPI. See [gss_wrap documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1331/overview-85/index.html)

GSSAPI is a generalized API for doing secure network applications. Kerberos is the mostly commonly used driver underneath GSSAPI.

If the application does not use GSSAPI, or the native kerberos messaging libraries, then it is likely using TLS to encrypt the traffic or the traffic is not encrypted.

Kerberos message encryption was designed to support relatively long lived tcp based client/server applications ( think telnet or ssh ). The API does not always map well to the way current applications are architected. Kerberos support is often bolted on well after the application is under construction 
and is only used for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Kerberos is an distributed service that is generally used for [secure authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) only. It does neither ensure that a user has the required permissions to access a resource (that would be Authorization) however it may be used to encrypt arbitrary data. As per [RFC 3961 "Encryption and Checksum Specifications"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3961) which extends and correct aspects of [RFC 1510](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1510) the Kerberos protocol provides confidentiality and integrity services.

While Kerberos can be used to encrypt information passed between authenticated peers in many cases it only performs the authentication step. Thus, you will find that Kerberos is used as component in a secure environment to ensure a secure authentication with other components and protocols handling the authorization and the secure transport.

In the end, it heavily depends on your usa-case to determine if the tradeoffs between using Kerberos or something else as a transport protocol make sense for you.

While the Kerberos protocol can be used to provide encryption services on most platforms, microsoft provides no mechanism to do this directory. Instead GSSAPI may be used to call these services.

For example, Active Directory uses Kerberos for message integrity.

Similarly, you could use e.g. TLS or IPsec to encrypt your data on the wire and combine it with Kerberos for authentication. But again, this is another protocol performing the actual transport encryption and just using Kerberos as an authentication component.

Comment: Kerberos can be used to encrypt any communiction after authentication has been performed. Most protocols supporting Kerberos only use it for authentication, but it doesn't have to be. The most common example of such use of Kerberos is secure NFS.